# Incrementing a counter based on some value with np.where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to get a counter to increase as I process an Pandas series using np.where based on some time differencesin days. For example, if I have a series with the following values:

```
Date        Value
01/03/2017  5
02/03/2017  8
03/03/2017  3
04/03/2017  7
12/03/2017  1
13/03/2017  3
14/03/2017  4
```

I will go to a series that looks like this through this code

```
df['DIFF'] = df['Date'].diff()/np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```

To produce this dataframe.

```
Date        Value  DIFF
01/03/2017  5      0
02/03/2017  8      1
03/03/2017  3      1
04/03/2017  7      1
12/03/2017  1      8
13/03/2017  3      1
14/03/2017  4      1
```

I then want to create a lifetime that counts the number of lives, on the assumption that a time diff greater than say 4 would be a new instance of a lifetime.

```
Date        Value  DIFF   LIFETIME
01/03/2017  5      0      1
02/03/2017  8      1      1
03/03/2017  3      1      1
04/03/2017  7      1      1
12/03/2017  1      8      2
13/03/2017  3      1      2
14/03/2017  4      1      2
```

I think I'm almost there with this code

```
df['LIFE'] = np.where(df['DIFF'] >=4, life_counter=df.shift(-1)+1, df.shift(-1))
```

The logic here would be that if the DIFF is greater than or equal 4, the I would set the LIFE variable to the previous + 1. Otherwise, it would be the same as the previous value. It seemed a neat way to carry state. However, my loop appears to ignore the state of what I've set, probably due to how np.where works. Does someone know a way to do what I'm doing and have it working. At present, my output looks like this.

```
Date        Value  DIFF   LIFETIME
01/03/2017  5      0      1
02/03/2017  8      1      1
03/03/2017  3      1      1
04/03/2017  7      1      1
12/03/2017  1      8      2
13/03/2017  3      1      1
14/03/2017  4      1      1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you simply want a cumulative sum on a boolean array, augmented by `1`:

```
>>> df
         Date  Value  DIFF
0  01/03/2017      5     0
1  02/03/2017      8     1
2  03/03/2017      3     1
3  04/03/2017      7     1
4  12/03/2017      1     8
5  13/03/2017      3     1
6  14/03/2017      4     1
>>> df['LIFETIME'] = np.cumsum(df.DIFF >= 4) + 1
>>> df
         Date  Value  DIFF  LIFETIME
0  01/03/2017      5     0         1
1  02/03/2017      8     1         1
2  03/03/2017      3     1         1
3  04/03/2017      7     1         1
4  12/03/2017      1     8         2
5  13/03/2017      3     1         2
6  14/03/2017      4     1         2
```

Comment: Ah, very nice! :D That's a much better solution since it appears there's a problem with state when using np.where

Comment: @Eamonn I'm not sure what you mean by "a problem with state", but I think you mean that, `life_counter=df.shift(-1)+1, df.shift(-1)` gets evaluated before the function is called.

Comment: Yes, exactly. So even if the 'state' of the previous value of life was changed to 2, it's not seen by the next row evaluation.